# Problem with code for generalized dijkstra using virtual function. No match for call to

Tags: c++

I am trying to make a generalized version of dijkstra using virtual functions to be able to handle different input. The problem for me is that I am now getting an error "No match for call to" and I can't seem to figure it out.

```
std::string dijkstra_generalized(Node* start, Comparator comparator)    {
NodeSet ns{};
start->setValue(0);
ns.add(start);
Node* dest;
while (!ns.isEmpty())
{
  Node* n = ns.removeMin();
  for (Edge e : n->getEdges())
  {
    int value = comparator(&n, e); <--error
    Node* d = e.getDest();
    int a = n->getValue() + value;
    if (a < d->getValue())
    {
      d->setValue(a);
      d->setParent(n);
      ns.add(d);
      dest = d;
    }
  }
}
```

**Header File**:

```
class Comparator{
public:
    virtual int operator()(Node& node, Edge edge) const {}
};

class DistComparator:public Comparator {
    int operator()( Node& node, Edge edge) const override {
        return edge.getLength();
    }
};

class LocComparator:public Comparator {
    int operator()(Node& node, Edge edge) const override {
        return 1;
    }
 };
 void dijkstra(Node* start);
 std::string dijkstra_generalized(Node* start, Comparator comparator);
```

What we want is for the comparator to return a value based on which kind of comparator it is. If the comparator input is Distcomparator, then it shall use the function in that class. We then use this value for our djikstra function to be able to give a generalized dijkstra.

I am getting this error message:

> dijkstra.cc:19:35: error: no match for call to ‘(Comparator) (Node**, Edge&)’
>        int value = comparator(&n, e);

Comment: Is the error you show the *only* message from the compiler? Please copy-paste the *full* and *complete* output.

Comment: And remember that symbols needs to be declared *before* they are used. So to use `Comparator` you need to declare it before the `dijkstra_generalized` function. It's not like that in the code you show, so either you get more errors than you show, or the code you show isn't a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have confused `&` with `*` operator.

`n` is pointer, so by `&n` you are getting pointer to pointer and it doesn't match  `Node&` as first param of `operator()`. You need to dereference (by *) `n` node:

```
Node *n = ns.removeMin();
for (Edge e : n->getEdges()) {
  int value = comparator(*n, e);
```

---

Now your `comparator` is passed by value so it always will call `operator()` from base class. You should pass it by pointer/reference so that calls of virtual functions work properly:

```
std::string dijkstra_generalized(Node *start, Comparator* comparator)
   ///...
   int value = (*comparator)(*n, e);
```